# Testing Backbone with jasmine got error Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I write Backbone.Collection to load JSON file and use in Backbone.View

Here is my Backbone.Collection

```
class Backbone.Config extends Backbone.Collection

  initialize: (filename = 'settings') ->
    @_load(filename)

  # private load setting file
  _load: (filename) ->
    @fetch
      url : "/assets/backbone/config/#{filename}.json"
      error: (e,data) ->
        if data.status == 404
          throw "Exception: Cant find such a file #{filename}.json"
        else if data.status == 200
          throw "Exception: can't load json file. please check your JSON syntax"

  get: ->
    @.toJSON()[0]
```

I use it in my Backbone.View

like this

```
 error: ->
     @displayMessage @config.get().form.display_message.error, 'red', 3000
```

this works well but when I wrote test for it with jasmine,

describe 'events', ->

```
 beforeEach ->
    @view.config       = new Backbone.Config()
    @successSpy        = sinon.spy @view, 'success'
    @errorSpy          = sinon.spy @view, 'error'
    @displayMessageSpy = sinon.spy @view, 'displayMessage'
    @confirmUnloadSpy  = sinon.spy @view, 'confirmUnload'
    @formChangedSpy    = sinon.spy @view, 'formChanged'
    @view.delegateEvents()

  it "success will called when 'ajax:success' is fired and form error has occured", ->
    @view.$el.trigger 'ajax:success', ['',{'error','','','error_message'}, '']
    expect(@successSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  it "fail ajax request, will call error method", ->
    @view.$el.trigger 'ajax:failure'
    expect(@errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(@displayMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  it 'confirmUnload called when page reloaded', ->
    @view.$el.trigger 'beforeunload'
    expect(@confirmUnloadSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  it 'when form changed, formChanged method call', ->
    @view.$el.trigger 'change'
    expect(@formChangedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

but I got a error in jasmine

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
```

So, my question is

**why I got a error when I test Backbone.View using Backbone.Collection in it? >**

Comment: (1) Why is Config a collection? (2) Collection already have a `get` method, overriding it might cause problems. (3) What makes you think that `fetch` (an AJAX call) has gotten its data when you call `@config.get()`?

Comment: (1) i'd like to collect magic numbers in js and use it
(2) i c! thx, ill fix it
(3) json data has loaded when instantiation

Comment: But `@fetch` is an AJAX call and `get` returning `undefined` smells like a "the AJAX hasn't finished yet" problem. What happens if you replace the `@fetch` call with a simple inlined assignment to force everything to happen synchronously?

Comment: thx, i solved :) exactly, ajax returns 'readyState: 1' because of ajax not finished. so i wrote `async: false` and test is success :)